# AsyncTask -> Error :Thread…: reacting to signal 3 Wrote stack traces to tombstoned (smartphone with android 10)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**My app crashes only on a smartphone with android 10 ... not on a smartphone with android 9 Why?**

This is my error:

> Thread[7,tid=8537,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x70f8fa2c00,peer=0x131c0378,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
>   Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

onCreate method (NetActivity.java):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NetClient task = new NetClient();
            payload = task.execute(ip, String.valueOf(Global.config_device), Global.uid, network.getSSID(), password, friendlyName).get();
        }
    }
});
```

My AsyncTask (NetClient.java):

```
public class NetClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader buffer = null;
    String ip;
    int port = 8899;
    String response = "";
    int errors = 0;
    private String[] conn_errors = {"", String.valueOf(R.string.error_provision), "Error: socket close...", "Error: receiving message...", "Unknown error...", "Error disconnecting socket..."};

    protected Boolean connect() {
        boolean res = false;
        try {
            if (socket == null) {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    res = true;
                }
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR connect", e.getMessage());
            errors = 1;
        }

        return res;
    }

    protected void disConnect() {
        if (socket != null) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errors = 5;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void sendData(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            out.write(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    protected String receiveData() {
        try {
            String message = "";

            message = buffer.readLine();
            message += buffer.readLine();
            message += buffer.readLine();
            message += buffer.readLine();
            message += buffer.readLine();

            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errors = 3;
            return "Error receiving response:  " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        boolean conn;
        ip = params[0];
        String message = "Teste sample" ;

        try {
            conn = connect();
            Log.w("NetClient", "" + conn);
            if (conn) {
                sendData(message);
            } else {
                errors = 2;
            }
            if (conn) {
                response = receiveData();
            } else {
                errors = 2;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("NetClient", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            errors = 4;
        } finally {
            disConnect();
            Log.i("NetClient", "Finished");
            return response;
        }

        return String.valueOf(errors);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.w("onProgressUpdate", "Progress: " + progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (errors == 0) {
            Log.i("onPostExecute", "Payload [" + result.length() + "] : " + result);
        }

        if (errors > 0) {
            Log.i("ERROR", conn_errors[errors]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will find the actual stack trace inside the tombstoned file which is inside data/ folder. more info [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug)

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to solve a NullPointerException [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)